# Which is the best way to parallelly running multiple tasks in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a function:

```
import time

def all_40k():
    for _ in range(400000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    all_40k()
    print(f'used time:{time.time()-start_time}')
```

The output is:

```
used time:9.545064210891724
```

Because this a same function repeated 40k times,so I want to have 4  parallelly functions running at the same time each function running 10k,ideally this will be 4 times faster.

So I first tried multiple threading:

```
import threading
import time
def first_10k():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')


def second_10k():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')

def third_10k():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')

def forth_10k():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=first_10k)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=second_10k)
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=third_10k)
thread4 = threading.Thread(target=forth_10k)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
thread4.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    thread3.join()
    thread4.join()
    print(f'used time:{time.time()-start_time}')
```

To my surprise ,the output is:

```
used time:23.058093309402466
```

And then I tried asyncio:

```
import time
import asyncio

async def test_1():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')


async def test_2():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')


async def test_3():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')


async def test_4():
    for _ in range(100000):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')


async def multiple_tasks():
  input_coroutines = [test_1(), test_2(), test_3(),test_4()]
  res = await asyncio.gather(*input_coroutines, return_exceptions=True)
  return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
  start_time = time.time()
  res1, res2 ,res3,res4 = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(multiple_tasks())
  print(f'used time:{time.time()-start_time}')
```

The output is:

```
used time:9.295843601226807
```

In the end I tried ProcessPoolExecutor:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
def data_handler(urls):
    for i in range(urls[0], urls[1]):
        print('validate')
        print('parsing')
        print('inserting')

def run():
    urls = [(1,100000),(100001,200000),(2000001,300000),(300001,400000)]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as excute:
        excute.map(data_handler,urls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    run()
    stop_time = time.time()
    print('used time %s' % (stop_time - start_time))
```

The output is:

```
used time 12.726619243621826
```

So how can I speed up the process? I think I went the wrong way.Any friend can help? Best regards!

Comment: new threads or processes need some time to create it and for small data finally it may need more time. It can be useful for bigger data. With thread can be also problem that Python has `GIL` which runs only one thread a time (not all at the same time) and thread can be useful only for problems which use `input-output` like requests to webpages or files. Similar problem can be with `asyncio` which works in similar way and can be useful only with functions which asyncio functions like `asyncio.sleep` or functions to read data from files or network. For `print()` it will not gives results.

Comment: better try it on real code which uses urls to get data from server instead of using `print()` - and it may works faster in parallel. You could use [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) which uses `asyncio`

Comment: Hi @furas I really appreciate your reply,after I use some real function I find,both ProcessPoolExecutor and thread works, saved half of time. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so what you noticed:

```
No parallelism   9.545064210891724
asyncio          9.295843601226807
multithreading   12.726619243621826
Thread Pool      23.058093309402466
```

First off, Asyncio doesn't actually use threads, and performance if you can guess it, relies on there being some I/O. Asyncio alternates between tasks in a loop, switching whenever one hits an `await`. If `await` is not used it will just end up running each of the tasks one at a time, and not switch at all.

With threads, only one thread is able to hold the control of the Python interpreter, due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). What you end up with here is a bunch of contention from the different threads all trying to do work at the same time. This context switching is what's slowing down your app. Similar to asyncio, you really only get those speedups if you want to schedule other work while waiting on some I/O.

Okay, so now surely the multiprocessing case should have run faster.. right? Well, each process does has it's own interpreter lock, however, the holdup is in your `print` statements. Each process is being blocked trying to send their output to the same console pipe. Let me show you with an example.

Say we have a method to be run 4 times. Once serially and once in parallel

```
def run(thread):
    print(f"Starting thread: {thread}")
    for i in range(500000):
        print('foobar')
    print(f"Finished thread: {thread}")


def run_singlethreaded():
    start_time = time.time()

    for thread in ["local"] * 4:
        run(thread)

    stop_time = time.time()
    return stop_time - start_time


def run_multiprocessing():
    start_time = time.time()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as ex:
        ex.map(run, ["mp0", "mp1", "mp2", "mp3"])

    stop_time = time.time()
    return stop_time - start_time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    singlethreaded_time = run_singlethreaded()
    multiprocessing_time = run_multiprocessing()
    print(f"Finished singlethreaded in:  {singlethreaded_time}")
    print(f"Finished multiprocessing in: {multiprocessing_time}")
```

If we run this and print the timings you would be surprised to see:

```
Finished singlethreaded in:  10.513998746871948
Finished multiprocessing in: 12.252000570297241
```

Now if we changed the print to something more simple which would not cause an IO bottleneck:

```
def run(thread):
    print(f"Starting thread: {thread}")
    for i in range(100000000):
        pass
    print(f"Finished thread: {thread}")
```

You will get the parallelism speed up you expect:

```
Finished singlethreaded in:  9.816999435424805
Finished multiprocessing in: 2.503000020980835
```

---

The important take away here is that before parallelism can help you, you need to understand where you are resource constrained. In the case of IO bound applications, threading or asyncio can be helpful. In the case of CPU bound applications, multiprocessing can be useful. And there are other times where neither will really help you (like the `print` statement) because the bottleneck exists within a system external to the app. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @flakes I really appreciate your answer ,after I use some real function I find, both ProcessPoolExecutor and thread works, saved half of time. Thank you very much!

Comment: @William Glad to help. As a general rule, I prefer asyncio over multithreading over multiprocessing. Multiprocessing is a much more complex mechanism and will generally be slower for non CPU bound apps. Multiprocessing also makes sharing data more complicated as each process will have independent memory. Asyncio has benefits over multithreading as there is no context switching. Asyncio can be much faster and less complex in many cases, with the one downside that you need to use IO bound methods that implement the async interface, which is not always the case, esp for some third party libs.